# Hibernate java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: > org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jax-rs

Using hibernate on my jax-rs I'm getting this error:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /services/datesTest. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error Caused by:
> ```
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   connectors.Connector.buildSessionFactory(Connector.java:32)   at
>   connectors.Connector.getSessionFactory(Connector.java:37)     at
>   connectors.Connector.getSession(Connector.java:45)    at
>   mainproject.services.HibernateDatesTest.verifyToken(HibernateDatesTest.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
>     at connectors.Connector.buildSessionFactory(Connector.java:21)  ...
>   44 more Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
>     at connectors.Connector.buildSessionFactory(Connector.java:21)  at
>   connectors.Connector.getSessionFactory(Connector.java:37)     at
>   connectors.Connector.getSession(Connector.java:45)    at
>   mainproject.services.HibernateDatesTest.verifyToken(HibernateDatesTest.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Powered by Jetty://

My session builder class:

```
package connectors;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class Connector {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");

            //apply configuration property settings to StandardServiceRegistryBuilder
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());


            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }




    public static Session getSession(){
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
}
```

My Pom.xml:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       
>           resueue-ws
>           serverside
>           1.0
>       
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <artifactId>resqueue-mainproj</artifactId> <dependencies>
> <!-- our projects -->
>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>serverside</groupId>
>     <artifactId>resqueue-dal</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>serverside</groupId>
>     <artifactId>resqueue-srdlib</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
> </dependency>
> <!-- Jetty -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
>     <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
>     <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- Nimbus -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
>     <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
>     <version>2.9</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- Jersey -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- jUnit -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>junit</groupId>
>     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>     <version>4.10</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <!--org.apache.http -->
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
>     <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
>     <version>4.3.2</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- JSON LIB -> added for testing only  -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2.4</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- Hibernate -->
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>     <version>5.1.30</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>     <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>     <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

I cleaned the maven repo from all other versions.
Any ideas?

Comment: what about hibernate version

Comment: its written in the pom file 4.3.6 final

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you have removed all of the previous version(s) of Hibernate from your classpath.

Looking at it on github, I do not see why that would be caused unless you were having class loader issues caused by version conflicts, as the `IntegratorServiceImpl` exists in both versions that you are/were using, which suggests a class loader issue to me

Comment: @Menai I am facing the exact same issue after I updated hibernate version from 4.1.10 to 5.3.1.
Can you please tell me what was the issue in your case and how to fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with following code

Also are you sure there are no multiple versions of hibernate jars in your classpath.

```
public class Connector {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");

            //apply configuration property settings to StandardServiceRegistryBuilder
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());


            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }
        return sessionFactory;
    }




    public static Session getSession(){
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this core;

If you have apache tomcat you need add ojbc6 in apache/lib

[OJBC6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

```
<!-- ORACLE JDBC driver, need install yourself -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```