# NoSuchMethodError when connecting to the MySql server with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish

I'm getting this error when I try to run the code and open the glassfish server:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
```

Here is my code :

```
public class SessionFact {
static SessionFactory sf;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFact() {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("Resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
        cfg.getProperties()).build();
        sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        System.out.println("build session factory ---------");
        return sf;
    }   
}
```

and my servlet:

```
public class Testing extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SessionFactory sf = HelpingClasses.SessionFact.getSessionFact();
    PrintWriter pr = resp.getWriter();
    pr.print("looks like is done");
}
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="Bean.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: > org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444185/hibernate-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-integrator-internal-integ)

Comment: Please show full error message (and further stack trace) for better context.